# Laravel eloquent update, 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, eloquent

I want to update my database with Laravel eloquent update, but response is always `500`

This is my model

```
class Tunggakan extends Model
{
protected $table = 'kredit_tunggakan';
/**
 * @var array
 */
}
```

This is the function

```
public function statusTunggakan(){

    $status = Tunggakan::find(2);
    $status -> id_status = 77;
    $status -> save();
}
```

This is the route

```
Route::prefix('tunggakan')->group(function () {
Route::post('/statusTunggakan','TunggakanControl@statusTunggakan');
});
```

Exception:

```
[2022-03-24 11:20:14] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'kredit_tunggakan.updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: update kredit_tunggakan set id_status = 77, kredit_tunggakan.updated_at = 2022-03-24 11:20:14 where id = 2) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'kredit_tunggakan.updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: update kredit_tunggakan set id_status = 77, kredit_tunggakan.updated_at = 2022-03-24 11:20:14 where id = 2)
```

Thanks before, for helping..

Comment: Log details will have more infro about what is happening. We can't help you without knowing the exact error you are getting. You can find the log details in `storage/logs` directory.

Comment: [2022-03-24 11:20:14] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'kredit_tunggakan.updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: update `kredit_tunggakan` set `id_status` = 77, `kredit_tunggakan`.`updated_at` = 2022-03-24 11:20:14 where `id` = 2) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'kredit_tunggakan.updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: update `kredit_tunggakan` set `id_status` = 77, `kredit_tunggakan`.`updated_at` = 2022-03-24 11:20:14 where `id` = 2)

Comment: your migration?

Comment: @DenaAchmad Don't post code in the comments, hard to read/understand. Instead, please [edit] your question and paste all relevant information there. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loking at the exception:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'kredit_tunggakan.updated_at
```

Seems like you don't have `updated_at` column in your database table. There are two solutions for this:

I: Create/update your migration to include `timestamp` fields:

```
 $table->timestamps();
```

II: Set `timestamps` to `false` when updating the record:

```
$status = Tunggakan::find(2);
$status->timestamps = false;
$status -> id_status = 77;
$status -> save();
```